Microsoft Identity URL Token IIS Errors
I tried all that I could find on how to fix this, so I got many different errors at different tries. But everytime I solve an Invalid Token error in my localhost, I get an URL error in my IIS. These are my last working localhost codes:
I have a web api endpoint that calls an async method that sends the e-mail confirmation link with the token:
var token = await _userManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user);
byte[] tokenGeneratedBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token);
var codeEncoded = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(tokenGeneratedBytes);
var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Auth", new { userId = user.Id, code = codeEncoded }, protocol: HttpContext.Request.Scheme);

Then inside the [HttpGet] async Task ActionResult ConfirmEmail:
var codeDecodedBytes = WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code);
var codeDecoded = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(codeDecodedBytes);
var confirmResult = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, codeDecoded);

This is one of the ways it works locally, but as soon as I try it on the server, I get:
Bad Request - Invalid URL
HTTP Error 400. The request URL is invalid.

Other implementations that work on localhost, but not in IIS:

Encoding the token with WebUtility or HttpUtility and decoding them the same way
When decoding, also applying some replaces like code.Replace("%25", "%") or .Replace(" ", "+")

In IIS, I tried both configurations:
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxUrlLength="4096" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
    </security>
</system.webServer>

To me, I passed the Invalid Token error, even thou it still can happen in IIS if I change the approach, but IIS is treating it in a completely different way.
Any solutions for this scenario?
Thanks!

You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 400 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.
